# Instantons as a -1 dimensional object

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, branes, instantons

I don't know much about Instantons, and looking through the Wiki page it seems like one must have a lot of knowledge about QFT to understand them. However recently I've encountered a statement (which I cannot refer to or extract more information) that instantons are "-1 dimensional" objects in the context of string theory.

The explanation is that if a 0-dimensional object (pointlike-particle) creates 1D worldline the spacetime, the 1-dimensional object (string) creates 2D worldsheet in the spacetime, instanton can create 0D-event(s) in spacetime.

- How can it be a -1 dimensional object? Can you explain it in more details?
- Are there any materials about instantons (which deals with some simple technical aspects) you can present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where a string carves out a $2$-dimensional world-sheet and a point particle carves out a $1$-dimensional world-line of spacetime, the [instanton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton) carves out a $0$-dimensional world-point. Counting only spatial dimensions, a string is $1$-dimensional and a point particle is $0$-dimensional. By logical extension, an instanton has dimension $-1$, if we only count spatial dimensions; intuitively because, except for an single instant of time, it is not there.

Concerning resource recommendations for [instantons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instantons):

1. S. Coleman, *Aspects of symmetry,* Chapter 7. (Note that Coleman calls solitons for *lumps.*)
2. G. 't Hooft and F. Bruckmann, *Monopoles, Instantons and Confinement,* [arXiv:hep-th/0010225](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0010225).
3. Many QFT textbooks has a section on instantons, e.g., S. Weinberg, *QFT2,* Section 23.5; L.H. Ryder, *QFT,* Section 10.5.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=instantons+reference